# FabricException: The primary or stateless instance for the partition

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I am following a [tutorial](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipP3lBfVJgmzn01fya9eBk0AYSLP1K4eUq-DEqLFQ0AebthN46y93foVkUU8KgOGKQ?key=VDJQbDN2TGU1elJBOS1RekRJMTdvamk2b19sQ29n) from [[this book]](https://books.google.com/books/about/Programming_Microsoft_Azure_Service_Fabr.html?id=iMg_DAAAQBAJ&source=kp_cover):
[image]

I am getting the following exception:
[image]

There's no doubt that my nodes are running fine:[image]

Here's how my stateless service is setup:

```
internal sealed class MyStatelessService : StatelessService
    {
        public MyStatelessService(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Optional override to create listeners (e.g., TCP, HTTP) for this service replica to handle client or user requests.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A collection of listeners.</returns>
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceInstanceListener[0];
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This is the main entry point for your service instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">Canceled when Service Fabric needs to shut down this service instance.</param>
        protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // TODO: Replace the following sample code with your own logic 
            //       or remove this RunAsync override if it's not needed in your service.

            long iterations = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "Working-{0}", ++iterations);

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

The way I deploy and get this exception:[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How can I get my client connected to my cluster?**

The entire solution can be viewed [here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B47fuJY78GQhaElsWTduSFhMOG8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your `ICalculatorService` have to be defined in another library project, in order to be shared between your stateless service library and your client project. So:

   - Create a new library project `MyStatelessService.Interfaces`
   - Add to it NuGet package: `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting`
   - Define in this library your `ICalculatorService`
   - Remove `ICalculatorService` from your other two projects
   - Add a reference to `MyStatelessService.Interfaces` to your client application and your stateless service library.
   - Fix references to `ICalculatorService`
   - All your `ICalculatorService` should be referenced from the same library

Your client will be:

```
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Client;
using MyStatelessService.Interfaces;
using System;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var calculatorClient = ServiceProxy.Create<ICalculatorService>
        (new Uri("fabric:/CalculatorService/MyStatelessService"));

    var result = calculatorClient.Add(1, 2).Result;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

2. Change your `MyStatelessService`'s `Program.cs` part after the `try` statement with this:

   ```
   ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("MyStatelessServiceType",
       context => new CalculatorService(context)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

   ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, typeof(CalculatorService).Name);
   ```

Instead of `CalculatorService`, you were referencing `MyStatelessService`.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to access your service through remoting, but your service is not enabled for remoting.

You need to return a [communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting) listener from `CreateServiceInstanceListeners` and implement `IService`.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your stateless service you called your service `MyStatelessService` instead of `CalculatorService` and you called your application `CalculatorService` instead of `CalculatorApplication`. As the book states at step 1 under 'The first version' "Create a new Service Fabric **application** named CalculatorApplication with a **service** named CalculatorService". You created an application named `CalculatorService` and a service called `MyStatelessService`. You then made a new service file within the stateless service project. You should **never** create a new service within a service. Use the generated `service.cs` (`MyStatelessService.cs` in your case) file instead. One way to solve your problem is to copy the implementation of `CalculatorService` into your stateless service and delete `CalculatorService.cs`. Your stateless service will be:

```
internal sealed class MyStatelessService: StatelessService, ICalculatorService
{
    public MyStatelessService(StatelessServiceContext serviceContext) : base(serviceContext)
    {

    }

    public Task<int> Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<int>(a + b);
    }

    public Task<int> Subtract(int a, int b)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<int>(a - b);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[] { new ServiceInstanceListener(context => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context)) };
    }
}
```

However, it's unconventional to call an application 'service', so I'd recommend to create a new project and paste your current implementation into it.

When creating a new project, name your application **CalculatorApplication**.
[image: Adding the application]

And then create the service with the name **CalculatorService**.
[image: Adding the service]

Your `CalculatorService.cs` file is made automatically, so just paste your current implementation into it. (The same as MyStatelessService above, but with the name CalculatorService.)